# rdesktop from osx to pi running arch linux

Tags: archlinux, remote

I want to connect via rdesktop to my Pi running ArchLinux with awesome WM.
I installed xrdp, enabled it and my xinit.rc contains exec awesome for WM startup.

If I now want to connect with:

```
rdesktop -u NAME 192.168.1.8
```

I get this:

```
ERROR: connect: Network is unreachable
```

but I dont really understand why i fails to connect because all services are running.

Comment: "Network is unreachable" means network is unreachable. Does your Pi box pings from your OSX?

Comment: Yes I can connect via ssh to my pi

Comment: Then it doesn't look like Pi problem. I'm not an OSX user, may be you should correct rdersktop invocation. Check this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54918/command-line-arguments-for-remote-desktop-connection-for-mac

Comment: But rdesktop works with raspbian without any problema.

Comment: Well, without any details it is hard to diagnose. Try to recheck xrdp configuration https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrdp, try exact port with `rdesktop -p`. See `systemctl status xrdp` and actual open ports `netstat -l' (`net-tools` package). I use Arch too, but didn't mess with `xrdp`